# Autoloading an app in spotify

Tags: spotify

Looking to auto-load an app into the Spotify desktop client.  Is this possible?  I get my app to run via the string.  Can it be loaded though the command line some how?

Answer (score 2):

Try starting the desktop client with the -uri parameter.

Example for the Mac OS X client (replace 'musixmatch' with the name of the app that you want to open):

> /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotify -uri spotify:app:musixmatch

If you want to use a link to the application, use open.spotify.com, like so:

> http://open.spotify.com/app/musixmatch